# I got an American visa, but ended up not traveling. Could this have implications on future travel?

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

Few years ago I got an American Visa in order to work there, but at the end I did not travel, this year I want to apply for a Schengen visa. Could I have any problem since in my passport I have an American visa that has expired?

Comment: I don't see how. If anything, a valid US visa could be an asset when applying for a Schengen visa. An expired one, used or not, is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

An expired visa in your passport should not be a problem.  Perhaps they may wish to know why you didn't use it, but if anything having been approved by the USA is a good thing, as USA visas are often more difficult to get than Schengen visas.

darn, Relaxed types faster than me ;-)